# How to index a substring between numbers in python

Tags: python, string

I have multiple similar looking strings like this:

```
s1 = 'carrots12509600apple2950950'
s2 = 'zebra77899967apple5557880'
```

I want to find a way to index the starting point of the word `apple`, meaning I want to find the `n` which returns:

```
s1[n] = a
```

Given that all strings have the word `apple`, and it is between two numbers, is there a way to find the starting point of the substring 'apple' in each string? The length of numbers before and after the word `apple` is also the same for each string, but not the character before the number before `apple`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Locating the position of a regex match in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674391/python-locating-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string)

Comment: [`s1.index('apple')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) or [`s1.find('apple')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Answer (score 4):

```
'zebra77899967apple5557880'.index('apple')
```

or

```
'zebra77899967apple5557880'.find('apple')
```

`index` raises ValueError if the sub string does not exist in the string. `find` returns `-1`