# Trying to find the combination of certain characters in a long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, indexing

Given this long string s:

> ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA

I'm trying to find every occurence of the characters "ATG" and to print the index of the character that comes after every occurence of this combination.

I have already tried looping through the string, and have so far only been successful after finding the first occurrence of the characters "ATG" and to print out the index of the character after that, which is 8. My program however stops after this even though there are more occurrences of the characters "ATG" in the string.

```
for y in range(len(s)):
    y = s[i : i + 3]
    i = i + 3
    if y == 'ATG':
        print(s.index(y)+3)
```

In this part of the code 's' is the string.
The result is 8 as it finds the first occurance of "ATG" and prints out the index of the character after that. My expected result should be 8, 110, 278, 336 and 340. It would seem the loop stops after finding "ATG" for the first time instead of going all the way through the string until it ends.

Comment: Hey :) You managed to pack quite a lot of logical errors in those 5 lines :)
I'll address them all in an answer, but until then, I'm curiouse about those things: Why do you use y as your `range` counter variable, and then overwrite it in line 2? What is `y`, why do you do `i = i + 3`, are you programming a second counter variable here, although you already have `y`? Why do you use `y` as the string variable one line later? Why do you do yet another lookup with `.index` later? Why do you add 3 to the lookup?

Comment: Got those reasons because of trial and error, did not really have any reasons to do it like that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i=0
while True:
    i=s.find("ATG",i)
    if i == -1: break
    i+=3
    print(i)
```

Comment: I would have used `while True: ...; i += 3; print(i)`.

Comment: @Finomnis, this works, why do you think it is deficient?

Comment: Holy crap, it does! This is hillarious, and amazing. I completely misjudged you. I am so sorry. This is actually the best solution, because it is most likely the fastest! (Besides the regex one) Also, I now understand why you suggested the `i += 3`.

Comment: Also, I downvoted too early and in hindsight without a clear understanding of what you were trying to accomplish. Now I cannot change the vote unless you edit. So, if you incorporate @wwii 's suggestion, you get another upvote ;)

Comment: Actually if OP intends to find overlapping occurrences of the sub string then my comment about advance by three instead of one is wrong.

Comment: @wwii I agree, but as "ATG" is hard coded, I don't think it matters. Also damn, still can't take back my downvote :( sorry! You would deserve it. Take this comment instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you were *trying* to code:

```
s = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"

search_str = 'ATG'
for y in range(len(s)-len(search_str)+1):
    sub_str = s[y : y + 3]
    if sub_str == search_str:
        print(y+len(search_str))
```

```
8
110
278
336
340
```

---

In case you need a one-liner for the fixed string `'ATG'`, here you go:

```
res = [n+3 for n in range(len(s)-2) if s[n:n+3] == 'ATG']
print(res)
```

```
[8, 110, 278, 336, 340]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling with this a lot but your example makes a lot of sense. How did I not think of it earlier..

Comment: Also, look at the replies of Brendan and Deepstop, they are both faster and better than mine. Mine is just the closest one to what you were trying to do, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with regex

```
import re
helix = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"

iter = re.finditer(r"ATG", helix)
indices = [m.end(0) for m in iter]
print(indices)
```

Result is `[8, 110, 278, 336, 340]`.
I found this technique is [already in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674391/python-locating-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string/16360404)

Just for fun, recoded this as a function that allows you to specify whether you want overlap (following assumes `helix` is already defined).

```
import re

def locate(haystack, needle, overlap=False):
    iter = re.finditer(f'(?=' + needle + r')' if overlap else needle, haystack)
    return [m.end(0) for m in iter]

print(locate(helix, 'ATG'))
print(locate(helix, 'CCC', True))
```

Result:

```
[8, 110, 278, 336, 340]
[15, 16, 17, 63, 68, 69, 82, 83, 177, 194, 195, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 278, 330]
```

Comment: This would be the way I would do it!

Comment: Didn't read the instructions properly, the output should be the position *after* the strings, meaning `+3`.

Comment: Odd, but sure. I will update to `m.start(0) + 3` (and yes, if I read questions better I would probably have won more scholarships back in the day).

Comment: @Deepstop Don't use `m.start(0) + 3`. Just use `m.end()`.

Comment: @blhsing thank you for the improvement. I've incorporated it.

Comment: Note that this solution does not return the indices of overlapping occurrences, which the intended logic of the OP's code does.

Comment: Yes I thought about overlap, but considered that ATG wouldn't overlap in any case so I didn't worry about it. However, say we wanted 'CCC' as the search which overlaps in several places, we could use `iter = re.finditer(r'(?=CCC)', helix)` instead.

Comment: @blhsing Not sure what the intended logic of OP's code is, code quite unclear :)

Comment: One more edit just for fun, adding a function that does overlapped or non-overlap.

Comment: :D lol you are going nuts with this. Why don't you post an external rust solution? :P Appreciate it though, I really like the regex solution. But it isn't something that a beginner would likely adopt.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of y and i. i is not defined for each iteration. What is think you are trying to do is,

```
idx = 0

while idx < len(s) - 2:
    tempStr = s[idx : idx + 3]
    if tempStr == 'ATG':
        print(s.index(idx)+3)
        idx += 3
    else:
        idx += 1
```

Comment: `len(s) - 2`, otherwise you'll miss the last element

Comment: Also, I think `index` is out of place here, why don't you just do `print(idx+3)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code, you are using y as index in the for loop and then as the string value.

You are incrementing i by 3, so you are checking occurrences of ATG only on indices 0,3,6,... You want to update the index by 1 at the time (which the for loop does for you) and then change the range so it will be `len(s)-2`.

```
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    y = s[i : i + 3] 
    if y == 'ATG':
        print(i+3)
```

Comment: Will access s[i+2] with i==len(s)-1, meaning s[s.len()+1], which is out of bounds.

Comment: I changed the range to `range(len(s)-3)` - I'll point it out in the answer itself

Comment: `range(len(s)-2)`, otherwise you won't find the last element

Comment: Also, print(i+3) to match OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner (modeled after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874144/6779606)):

```
>>> res = [n+3 for n in range(len(s)) if s.find('ATG', n) == n]
>>> res
[8, 110, 278, 336, 340]
```

Comment: Using the `find` method in a loop over the length of the input unnecessarily makes it cost *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity.

Comment: A solution with one line may be desired regardless of the time complexity, but it's good to know that it's not as efficient as other looping methods.

Comment: No. There is better solutions for one line.

Comment: I am not stopping you from posting that better one line solution :)

Comment: Done ;) :P and it isn't O(n^2)