# How to get the position of each character in string with python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

How can I get the position of a matched characters(small string) inside a string(fasta) in python?

I am using a fasta file as String to search for a motif using regular expression `'[AGCT][TG][TC][GT]TG'` along with the motif, I also wish to know and save the position of motif occurred in the string.

```
rdict = dict([ (x[1],x[0]) for x in enumerate(Seq) ])
motif = '[AGCT][TG][TC][GT]TG'
#for match in Seq:
matches = re.findall(motif, Seq.upper())
print(matches)
Seq.index(matches)
```

The above code does the work to search for the motif but returns only position of one character. How can I change this to give the start to end position of the motif(small string).

Comment: If you know the position of 1 character, you also know the length of the match is 6 so what can't you do ?

Comment: Maybe `matches = [x.span() for x in re.finditer(motif, Seq.upper())]`?

Comment: `iter = re.finditer(motif,Seq.upper()) indices = [m.start(0) for m in `iter]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674391/python-locating-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string/16360404 to get some ideas on how you can do this.

Comment: Yes, please let know if https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360404/3832970 answers your question.

Comment: Its basically calling the `start()` function of the match object. You have access to the matched substring and its position. Create your arrays, maybe an array of array's.

Comment: @sln .. thanks for the links but findall is the only option works with fasta sequences so far, I had tried finditer and re.search but they have issues with list of strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew .. thanks but re.search isn't good with lists.

Comment: Also, I tried something as ```binding = []
index = []
#print(matches)
for match in Seq:
    matches = re.findall(motif, Seq.upper())
    for char in matches:
        pos = Seq.index(matches[0])
        if len(matches) > 0:
            dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'index':pos, 'binding':matches })
            binding.append(matches)
            index.append(pos)
print(len(matches))        
dataframe.head()``` but the second loop with index is stuck at first position, any suggestions?

Comment: @Kay *re.search isn't good with lists* - I have nowhere advised to use `re.search`. What is your exact input? What is your exact expected output ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew @WiktorStribiżew input is fasta sequences that looks like this ```Seq=GGAGGGAGAAGCAGCCTGAACCGGGCTGGTCTCTCTGGGATTGGAGAGAAAGGTGGCGGAGaGCGGCGGGGGTGGGGGG``` and expected output is 
```+------+-------+---------+  
|      | start | binding |   
+------+-------+---------+ . 
|    0 |   210 | GGCTTG  | . 
|    1 |   317 | TTTTTG  | . 
|    2 |   389 | GGCGTG  | . 
| .... |    .. | ....    | . 
| .... |    .. | ....    | . 
|    3 |   810 | CGCGTG  | . 
|    4 |   810 | CTCTTG  | . 
+------+-------+---------+ . 
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple matches along with their start and end indices, use `finditer` instead:

```
matches = re.finditer(motif, Seq.upper())

for match in matches:
  string_matched = match[0]
  start_index = match.start(0)
  end_index = match.end(0)
```

Comment: Thanks ! but its throws error as ```ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index```

Comment: @Kay That's a pandas error, you didn't mention how you're using the above in a dataframe.

Comment: ```binding.append(string_matched)
start.append(start_index)
end.append(end_index)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({ 'binding':binding, 'start':start, 'end':end})
dataframe.head()```

Comment: Thanks for above, I 'm creating a list of matches and indices and then put them together in dataframe.