# How to find the index in a string in spark when I am dealing with a list?

Tags: python

How do I find the index of the numbers 0-9 in a string?

```
MyString = "Are all the black cats really black 045. I don't think so 098."
MyString.find([0-9])
```

> TypeError: must be str, not list

How do I get around this and replicate what essentially is a PATINDEX in SQL server?. The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674391/python-locating-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string/16360404) gives me a perspective of searching using regex but I am still unable to insert lists.

Comment: is this a Pyspark question or a Python question?

Comment: It's a python question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to find the numbers:

```
>>> [MyString.find(str(i)) for i in range(10)]
[36, -1, -1, -1, 37, 38, -1, -1, 60, 59]
```

If you want the smallest number, you can use `min`:

```
>>> min([j for j in [MyString.find(str(i)) for i in range(10)] if j != -1])
36
```

Or you can use `re.search` for use with a regex pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("[0-9]", MyString).start()
36
```

Remember to wrap the regex pattern in double quotes, otherwise it would be interpreted as a list of 0-9 (zero minus nine), which is -9.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I believe the actual position must be 37. I believe this is due to Python starting from 0.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be consistent with SQL behaviour you need to add 1. @Vinaybilla

Comment: Also, how do I go about if I need to start searching after position 10 similar to how we do for CHARINDEX in SQL?

Comment: `min([j for j in [MyString.find(str(i)) for i in range(10)] if j >= 9])` @Vinaybilla